# Parsing in Android application

Tags: c#, android, json, xamarin

I'm new in developing for android.

I wrote JSON parse that parse information from site API by pressing button
I need that program parse information automatically when Activity launches
How I can do this?

My code:

```
 button.Click += async (sender, e) =>
        {

            // Get the latitude and longitude entered by the user and create a query.
            string url = "http://new.murakami.ua/?mkapi=getProducts";
            JsonValue json = await FetchAsync(url);
            ParseAndDisplay (json);
        };
    }
        private async Task<JsonValue> FetchAsync (string url)
        {
            // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create (new Uri (url));
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "GET";

            // Send the request to the server and wait for the response:
            using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync ())
            {
                // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream ())
                {
                    // Use this stream to build a JSON document object:
                    JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run (() => JsonObject.Load (stream));
                //dynamic data = JObject.Parse(jsonDoc[0].ToString);
                //Console.Out.WriteLine("Response: {0}", jsonDoc[0].ToString);


                    // Return the JSON document:
                    return jsonDoc;
                }
            }
        }
    private void ParseAndDisplay(JsonValue json) {


     ImageView product = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.productimage);
        TextView name = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.posttitle);
        JsonValue firstitem = json[0];
        //Console.Out.WriteLine(firstitem["post_title"].ToString());
        name.Text = firstitem["post_title"];


   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move your code from the `onClick()` listener to some appropriate activity lifecycle event - like `onCreate()` or `onResume()`. Be sure that the UI is already initialised and you will be fine.

Comment: Just override onCreate() and move the call to your `FetchAsync` function in the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Write your code like this :

```
public class YourClassName extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
        string url = "http://new.murakami.ua/?mkapi=getProducts";
        JsonValue json = await FetchAsync(url);
        ParseAndDisplay (json);
     }
}
```